# Does SQL Server Express 2008 R2 eliminate the need to install MS SQL Server 2008 Express then SP1?

Tags: sql-server-2008

To install SQL Server 2008 plus SP1 on Win 7 machines, you have the following options:

1. install the deployment (runtime only - no management tools) version with SP1 built in
2. install the pre-SP1 version (with tools), then upgrade to SP1 (either by downloading SP1, or running windows update -- in either case a 262 MB download, because SP1 is for all editions of SQL server, not just the express edition)

Discussed in this article: social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/6b31a657-fe8a-4d72-a82f-b795f8b1daa3

"Microsoft Update experience far superior to having to run through the installer (again) and recomend using this approach rather than downloading and running the SP manually."

...except that is 262 MB a pop.

3. I then found a SP1 download here: [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlexpress/installing-sql-server-express-on-windows-7-release-candidate)

Does SQL Server Express 2008 R2 eliminate the need for this process?

Answer (score 1):

SQL 2008 R2 is a completely new release so in that sense yes, it does.  R2 is not a service pack to SQL 2008 so be aware that you'll be doing a version upgrade if you do have SQL 2008 installed anywhere already.